# Update only one association with simple_fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm wondering what is the best solution to individually update an associated record with `simple_fields_for`.

I have texts associated to an order. So this what I have in my view:

```
= f.simple_fields_for(:texts) do |ff|
  .card
    .card-body
      .order-text
        = ff.input( \
          :content,
          label: false,
          required: false,
          disabled: !@order.finalized?,
          input_html: { \
            class: 'form-control order-text-field',
            rows: 6,
            placeholder: '' })
          - if @order.finalized?
            br
            = ff.link_to_remove( \
                'Delete this text',
                data: { confirm: "Do you really want to delete this text?" })
```

I want to add a button under each text (like the link_to_remove) to perform a specific action + update the record.

For example, under the 2nd text, I would like to edit it, then click on a button to update ONLY this record (so I have to get the params of this specific text) + perform an action.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of action? Why the strict requirement to ONLY update that record? Rails is pretty smart when it comes to knowing what updates it need to do to the data.

Comment: Hi @bo-oz. I want to add a button that will update and then publish this text specifically. I'm using aasm_state so I just need to update the text then apply the aasm method to publish it, without publishing the others

Comment: This sound more like something that needs to be solved with an ajax request to a seperate route (`PATCH /texts/:id`) as its kind of outside the scope of what `accepts_nested_attributes`/`form_for` does. And before you ask "How do I do that?" - its a pretty broad question with plenty of tutorials available.